# how do I specify the source code directory in VS when looking at the call stack of a memory dump?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crash-reports, memory-dump

I am analyzing a .dmp file that was created and I have a call stack which gives me a lot of info.  But I'd like to double click on the call stack and have it bring me to the source code.

I can right click on the call stack and select symbol settings.. where I can put the location to the PDB.  But there is no option for the source code directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code directory is unfortunately hard coded into the pdb's however if you know the folders required you can use windows concept of symbolic links, junctions.

I use the tool [Junction Link Magic](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163563.aspx) about how to set up a Source Server (aka SrcSrv) integration at your site.

I took the time to follow these steps for our codebase, and now we are able to take a .dmp file from any build of our software in the past 6 months... get a stack trace with symbols... and view the exact source code lines in the debugger.  Since the steps are integrated into our automated builds, there's very little overhead now.

I did need to write a custom indexer for ClearCase, but they have pre-existing ones for Perforce, TFS, and maybe others.

It is worth noting that the .dmp support in VS2005 is a little shaky.. it's quite a bit more stable in VS2008.

You'll also need to configure Visual Studio to grab the symbols for the MS products from here in addition to your own symbol server:

```
http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

That is described in a few places such as on the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/debugstart.mspx) site.

Answer (score 2):

Windbg allows you to setup source paths same as PDB's paths.

Answer (score 0):

After loading the PDB, manually navigate to the source file that matches the current execution location.  A PDB contains the path and filename of the source files that built its associated binary, and I suspect the debugger is smart enough to hook things up when it notices that the filename being displayed and the filename associated with with current binary location, match.

Comment: It is not smart enough. Tested (at least in VS2005)

Comment: Bummer. The SDK debuggers (ntsd/cdb/windbg) are smart enough.